# Tensor contraction with Kronecker deltas in sympy

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to use sympy to do some index gymnastics for me. I'm trying to calculate the derivatives of a cost function that looks like

cost = sum<sub>i</sub> (M<sub>ii</sub>)<sup>2</sup>

where M is given by a rotation

M<sub>ij</sub> = U<sup>*</sup><sub>ki</sub> M<sup>0</sup><sub>kl</sub> U<sub>lj</sub>

I've written up a parametrization for the rotation matrix, from which I get the derivatives as products of Kronecker deltas. What I've got so far is

```
def Uder(p,q,r,s):
    return KroneckerDelta(p,r)*KroneckerDelta(q,s) - KroneckerDelta(p,s)*KroneckerDelta(q,r)

from sympy import *

# Matrix size                                                                                                                                                                                 
n = symbols('n')
p = symbols('p');
i = Dummy('i')
k = Dummy('k')
l = Dummy('l')

# Matrix elements                                                                                                                                                                             
M0 = IndexedBase('M')
U = IndexedBase('U')

# Indices                                                                                                                                                                                     
r, s = map(tensor.Idx, ['r', 's'])

# Derivative                                                                                                                                                                                  
cost_x = Sum(Sum(Sum(M0[i,i]*(Uder(k,i,r,s)*M0[k,l]*U[l,i] + U[k,i]*M0[k,l]*Uder(l,i,r,s)),(k,1,n)),(l,1,n)),(i,1,n))

print cost_x
```

but sympy is not evaluating the contractions for me, which should reduce to simple sums in terms of r and s, which are the rotation indices. Instead, what I get is

```
Sum(((-KroneckerDelta(_i, r)*KroneckerDelta(_k, s) + KroneckerDelta(_i, s)*KroneckerDelta(_k, r))*M[_k, _l]*U[_l, _i] + (-KroneckerDelta(_i, r)*KroneckerDelta(_l, s) + KroneckerDelta(_i, s)*KroneckerDelta(_l, r))*M[_k, _l]*U[_k, _i])*M[_i, _i], (_k, 1, n), (_l, 1, n), (_i, 1, n))
```

I'm using the latest git snapshot 4633fd5713c434c3286e3412a2399bd40fbd9569 of sympy.

Comment: I think there's a problem with the braces in your last expression.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - if I replace the braces with parentheses, I get the error `TypeError: 'IndexedBase' object is not callable`

Comment: The innermost sum is created incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks! How did I not see that..

Anyway, now the problem is that Sympy doesn't seem to be doing anything :D